# Numerical sum problem.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I just started the series chapter and I come across some series that I don't know how should I resolve them.
All of them have the same structure : 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n ...
$$
For example:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{n+1}{2^n} or $$
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{n^2}{2^n} 
$$
Some tips on how should i aproache this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I edited my post. Sorry it's n from 0 to infinity.

Comment: I suggest you change the upper value to $m$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, absorb  $(-1)^n$ with $\displaystyle\frac1{2^n}$ to find

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{n+1}{2^n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)\left(-\frac12\right)^n$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n-1)\left(-\frac12\right)^n+2\underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-\frac12\right)^n}_{\text{ Geomtric Series}}$$

For $|r|<1,$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n-1)r^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n-1)r^n=\frac{d \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r^n}{dr}$$

See also: [Elementary problems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770021/elementary-problems/770022)  and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)

Can you manage the last problem from here?

Comment: It is funny ! Today, you wrote at least twice $Geomtric$ $Series$. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, i will manage the second problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, Sorry for the repetition

Comment: @user137209, We can utilize http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence#Sum_to_infinite_terms for the problem I've answered

Comment: Don't be sorry, please ! I just found funny that, being almost blind, I noticed that. At least, it proves that I read what you write (so nicely) ! Cheers.